# How can i access a Queue in sabre Soap API

Tags: sabre

I used QueueAccessLLSRQ for access but when finish access the PNR removed out queue.

```
 <QueueAccessRQ Version="2.0.9" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Navigation Action="QR"/>
<QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="XXX" Number="1"/>
```

My problem: I want read data from queue and after remove it if i need.
Anyone can check for me to resolve this problem
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You are using "QR" which means to queue remove

You should use the following which will return you information about the first pnr on XXX/Q200

```
<QueueAccessRQ Version="2.0.9" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <QueueIdentifier Number="200" PseudoCityCode="XXX"/>
</QueueAccessRQ>
```

You can then send a request like this (same as your example) which  will remove that 1 pnr and return information about the next pnr

```
<QueueAccessRQ Version="2.0.9" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Navigation Action="QR"/>
<QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="XXX" Number="1"/>
  </QueueAccessRQ>
```

or you could send an Ignore request which will leave the pnr on the queue and return information about the next pnr. "Plus" is the number of pnrs to leave on queue, you would need to increment this by one each time you ignore another pnr on the same queue.

```
 <QueueAccessRQ Version=""2.0.8"" xmlns=""http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
                <Navigation><Direction Action=""I"" Plus=""1""/></Navigation>
                </QueueAccessRQ>
```

if you do not have enough information in the returned pnr response, you could send a GetReservationRQ to get full data on the pnr.

Comment: I don't believe that you can do any filtering or sorting by date using the soap or rest api. 
You must get each pnr and then use GetReservationRQ to get full pnr data and check the appropriate date field in the response

Comment: @DavidLeep Use `<ns:Selection Criteria="08JAN21-09JAN21" Function="CD"/>` or 
`<ns:Selection Criteria="6A-6P" Function="CR"/>` but not both.